# Is there a way to use a switch statement in JavaScript with a variable to display text based on another variable

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement, average, document.write

I am trying to get a switch statement to use a variable called "avg" for the average of five grades. The five grades are added together to get the total and then divided by five to get the average. Like this:

```
avg = +grade_one + +grade_two + +grade_three + +grade_four + +grade_five;
```

The switch needs to display five cases, one for each grade range, (i.e 90% to 100% = A). As well as the percentage itself.

I have tried using cases with numeric values like "case 1" for example, and then printing two lines of text but that won't work.

Should I try using an if-else structure before the switch to establish what each grade percentage equals in a letter, or will that not work?

Here is the code for the switch.

```
switch (avg)
{
case 1:
letter = "A";
per = "90-100";
document.write("Based on your semester average, your grade 
falls between " + per + "%");
document.write("you earned a " + letter);
break;

case 2:
letter = "B";
per = "80-89.9";
document.write("Based on your semester average your grade falls between " + per + "%");
document.write("you earned a " + letter);
break;

case 3:
letter = "A";
per = "70-79.9";
document.write("Based on your semester average your grade falls between " + per + "%");
document.write("you earned a " + letter);
break;

case 4:
letter = "D";
per = "60-69.9";
document.write("Based on your semester average your grade falls between " + per + "%");
document.write("you earned a " + letter);
break;

case 5:
letter = "F";
per = "Below 60%";
document.write("Based on your semester average your grade falls between " + per + "%");
document.write("you earned a " + letter);

default:
document.write("Invalid Entry");
break; 
}
```

Comment: You should not use `switch` at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a `switch` for that: the code for each case is too similar. The difference is just in a few values, which you can store in an array. Then find in that array in which segment the average falls, and build the output from that.

Also, don't use `document.write` for this. Instead create an element (like a `div`) that will contain the output message.

I don't know what the context is of your exercise, but I suppose there are some inputs with the 5 grades. Load those as an array (not as 5 distinct variables), and calculate the average in a generic way (not tied to 5).

Here is some suggested code in a runnable snippet:

```js
let thresholds = [100.1, 90, 80, 70, 60, 0];
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
let output = document.querySelector("div");
let button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    let grades = Array.from(inputs, inp => +inp.value);
    let avg = grades.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / grades.length;
    let i = thresholds.findIndex(min => avg >= min);
    let letter = "-ABCDF"[i];
    let low = thresholds[i];
    let high = thresholds[i - 1] - 0.1;
    let msg = `Based on your semester average, your grade falls between ${low}-${high}%\nYou earned a ${letter}.`;
    output.textContent = msg;
});
```

```html
Grades:
<ul>
<li><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="80" size="4">
<li><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="80" size="4">
<li><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="80" size="4">
<li><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="80" size="4">
<li><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="80" size="4">
</ul>
<button>Get grade</button>
<div></div>
```